# Remote GDB checkpoint/fork failure

Tags: c++, gdb, gdbserver

I am trying to debug on a remote target that does not support run or restart without a checkpoint. The only user available is root, so there shouldn't be any permission issues. I tried:

```
 Breakpoint 1, main (argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffe348) at foo.cpp:40
 (gdb) checkpoint
 checkpoint -1: fork returned pid 6145.
 Failed to find new fork
 (gdb) i checkpoints 
 No checkpoints.
```

Does anyone know how to get run to work? Or how I can check to see what is actually causing the fork to fail and prevent the checkpoint?

Comment: Obviously, the underlying implementation fails. It really looks like a bug, at least in the way it is handled...

Comment: I have gotten run to work using the answer from netskink, but the checkpoint fork still fails, even when using the "--multi" command line flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, add the following to your .gdbinit file

`target extended-remote <host>:<port>`

This should allow you to use the run command, eliminating the need to use restart.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fork how could you restore a checkpoint?  A checkpoint does a rewind to a processes saved state at a moment in time.  Once the fork occurs, I imagine the checkpoint would only exist for the original process.

From the manual there is this entry:

> Finally, there is one bit of internal program state that will be
>   different when you return to a checkpoint — the program's process id.
>   Each checkpoint will have a unique process id (or pid), and each will
>   be different from the program's original pid. If your program has
>   saved a local copy of its process id, this could potentially pose a
>   problem.

Regarding the required use of checkpoints to perform restarts on remote sessions.  I have never used checkpoints before but I have restarted many a remote session.